# WebApi using get parameter in middle of uri

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

Hello a bit of a newbie - using VS 2013 ASP.net WebApi - have specs for following uri:

```
/device/{deviceId}/register
```

Tried a few things like:

```
public class DeviceController : ApiController
{
        [Route("/{deviceId}/register")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(string deviceId)
        {
        }
}
```

And tried updating `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Device",
url: "device/{deviceid}/",
defaults: new { deviceId = "", action = "Register"}
);
```

Comment: Try `[Route("device/{deviceId}/register")]` instead. Your attribute routes and explicit config routes are separate from eachother.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your Route attribute call to:

```
[Route("device/{deviceId}/register")]
```

And remove all changes that you're done in RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes - they are not needed.

Then it will work fine. Attribute routing is not relative to routes defined in your HttpConfiguration object.